# Fullcalendar locale doesn't work in Chorme and Edge

Tags: javascript, browser, fullcalendar, locale, fullcalendar-5

I tried to see demo version of FullCalendar in Kazakh language(kk)
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/locale-demo

But when I switched browser to Edge, weekdays weren't translated

Edge:

[image]

The same problem appears while using Chrome:

[image]

But this problem does not appear in Firefox:

[image: Mozilla]

I didn't test it in other browsers. What should I do to fix it?

UPD: And this is not only kazakh language, I switched language to Albanian(sq), and same problem

[SQ with two browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abWrE.png)

first browser is Firefox, second is Chome

I even make kazakh language appear in top in Prefered languages:

[Prefered languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83o5z.png)

Comment: You'd have to ask the makers of those browsers to include Kazakh in the list of languages they support. The date-related data is supplied by the browser, not by fullCalendar (If you look at the latest [fullCalendar locales file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.11/locales-all.global.min.js) you'll see it doesn't contain date-related translations.

Comment: Alternatively you may be able to use one of the supported date plugins in fullCalendar, if that plugin provides its own translations for your chosen language - details at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting . I have not investigated whether any of those plugins provide translations of any sort, let alone whether they provide Kazakh translations...but you can do that research easily enough yourself.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for answer, I added Kazakh language in Chome -> Settings -> Preferred languages, but still, weekdays and month isn't translating. And this is not only kazakh language, I switched language to Albanian(sq), and same problem

Comment: It's not about the preferred language setting of the browser, I didn't say that. That only controls the _default_, it doesn't control what's used at other times. It's about what locales and languages the browser supports within the `DateTime` object in JavaScript. Open your browser's console and put `Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf('kk')` - if it returns an empty array then you know the locale is not supported in that browser. Contrast that with, for example `Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf('en')` where you will probably get an array back showing that English is supported.

Comment: Reference: Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/supportedLocalesOf